# Навигация в VrPanoramaView

Tags: android, vr

Начал изучать VrPanoramAView. И столкнулся с вопросом - как добавить элементы навигации, примерно такое:

[image: Пример]

Comment: А это разве не обычный объект?

Comment: @МаксимВласов, что под твоим понимаем Обычный Объект? и как его добавить в VrPanoramaView ?